# Julia updates variable

Tags: julia

I was just wondering, why Julia outputs the following

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a 
b.+=[5,5,5]
```

Then the variable a is updated as well, so after the code is run `a=[6,7,8]`.

Why is this? If the last line is `b+=[5,5,5]`, a isn't updated and stays `a=[1,2,3]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b = a` does not create a copy, but simply points the label `b` to the object referenced by `a`. When you do `b = something_else`, you just reassign the label `b` to point to something else. However once you change elements within `b` (i.e. not the binding), you are changing `a` as well, because they both point to the same underlying object. You don't even need `+=` to see this, just regular assignments will do:

```
julia> a = [1,2,3];

julia> b = a;

julia> b = 5;

julia> a
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> b = a;

julia> b[1] = 10;

julia> a
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 10
  2
  3
```

Now the difference between `.+=` and `+=` is that `b += [5, 5, 5]` means `b = b + [5, 5, 5]`, i.e. you're essentially doing `b = [6, 7, 8]`, thereby replacing the binding of `b`. If you do `b .+= [5, 5, 5]`, you are broadcasting the assignment elementwise, that is you are changing each element within `b`, but not the object (the vector holding your integers) which `b` points to, which in that case is still the same as `a`.

Answer (score 3):

In Julia when you write:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

you make a binding between name `a` and value `[1, 2, 3]`. This is an *assignment* operation.

Similarly when you write:

```
b = a
```

Julia makes a binding of name `b` to the same value (no copying is performed).

So after these first two operations names `a` and `b` are bound to the same value `[1, 2, 3]` (exactly the same object in memory).

Now the difference between:

```
b .+= [5, 5, 5]
```

and

```
b += [5, 5, 5]
```

is that `.+=` is a *broadcasting assignment* operation which is *in-place*. In-place means that the object that `b` name is bound to is updated. No new memory is allocated.

On the other hand `+=` is a standard assignment and in this case when you perform the addition of `[1, 2, 3]` (that `b` name points to) and `[5, 5, 5]` a new vector is allocated and bound to name `b`. However, this does not affect the original vector `[1, 2, 3]` that is still stored in memory. Since `a` name is bound to the `[1, 2, 3]` vector it is unaffected.

In summary: `.+=` is an in place operation, while `+=` allocates a new vector because addition of two vectors with `+` (non broadcasted) creates a new vector.

Finally let me highlight that the left hand side of the broadcasting assignment must be a container that allows for in-place update (technically a `copyto!` function is called).

Therefore we have the following:

```
julia> a = (1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)

julia> b = a
(1, 2, 3)

julia> b .+= (5, 5, 5)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching copyto!(::Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}, ::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Base.Broadcast.Style{Tuple}, Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, typeof(+), Tuple{Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}}})

julia> b += (5, 5, 5)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching +(::Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}, ::Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64})

julia> b = b .+ (5, 5, 5)
(6, 7, 8)

julia> a
(1, 2, 3)
```

The behavior you see is caused by the fact that `Tuple`s are immutable and also the `+` operation is undefined for them, but as you can see in the last line you can broadcasst `+` to add tuples, but this addition creates a new tuple.